# Example of probability space $\Omega$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Can anybody provide an example of probability space say $\Omega$, that is seperated in three disjoint and complementary events. s.t. each of those events has equal probability to occur, that is $1/3$.

I was trying to think the basic examples of fliping coins or dices etc but I could not think of some rule that provides the outcomes that I assume above.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ be the sample space of the values of throwing a dice. Let $A$ be the event that either $1$ or $2$ comes up. Let $B$ be the event that either  $3$ or $4$ comes up. Let $C$ be the event that either $5$ or $6$ comes up.

Then $$P(A)=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{3}=P(B)=P(C)$$

Meaning that they are of equal probability.

$$P(A\cap B)=P(A\cap C)=P(B\cap C)=P(A\cap B\cap C)=0$$

Meaning they are disjoint.

It follows that:

$$ P(A\cup B \cup C)=1$$

Comment: I think you're right.... I had something more complex in my mind...but...I shouldn't

Comment: What exactly do you mean by more complex?

Comment: Complex idea...not complex numbers :P